# WCF-endpoint listening

Tags: wcf, web-services

There was no endpoint listening at http;//localhost:8080/xdxservice/xdsrepository that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Comment: that's nice. what your question?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a typo in the question, but your URL is invalid.

```
http;//localhost:8080/xdxservice/xdsrepository
```

should have a colon rather than a semi-colon

```
http://localhost:8080/xdxservice/xdsrepository
```

This may well not be your problem, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

the url should have a .svc extention, no? (answered in comments)

Are you running the WCF in ASP.NET or the VS webserver?

Answer (score 0):

What service class is the .svc file pointing to? Is there a  section for this class in the web.config or app.config file? Does this  section have an  element defined?

If not running under IIS, does this  element have an address defined? Or does the  have a base address defined?

Answer (score 0):

This usually just means that the service is not running, or is otherwise not able to listen to requests. It could be the mistyped URL, or the IIS application is not started, or you have the wrong port number.

But basically, it means what the message says.